# Can i pass variables to AWS EC2 instances created with terraform and user_data? Or update an already created resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, user-data

I’m new on learning terraform with AWS and by i understand i can create an EC2 instances and pass it some Terminal commands (via “user_data”) in order to install software, etc…

I wonder if i can i install Docker, download a repository, build an image and deploy.

But if i have a fullstack app, and i have:

Instance_1: Backend

Instance_2: Frontend

How can i catch the IP of Instance_1 (via ‘output’) and pass it to the source code of the app of the frontend stored on Instance_2 in order to make the Frontend capable of connect to the Backend on Instance_1?.

I know that i can download source code via github and build it via Docker

if i create an EC2 instance

```
resource "aws_instance" "Mi_Primer_Servidor"{

  #Verificar el 'id' de la ami y las configuraciones con AWS
  ami="ami-056cb9ae6e2df09e8"

  #Seleccionamos el tipo de maquina virtual
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  #Asignamos una zona de disponibilidad (OPCIONAL)
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"

  #Se recomienda crear previamente la llave en AWS y descargar el archivo
  #O usar una llave ya existente
  key_name = "terraform"

  #Definimos la interfaz de red (OPCIONAL)
  network_interface {
    device_index = 0
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.mi_interfaz_de_red.id
  }

  #A continuacion haremos que la maquina virtual ejecute algunos 
  #comandosvia consola como instalar algunos programas 
  #En este caso vamos a instalar y ejecutar un servidor apache
  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              sudo apt-get update -y
              sudo apt-get upgrade -y
              sudo apt install apache2 -y
              sudo systemctl start apache2
              sudo bash -c 'echo Mi primer servidor con terraform > /var/www/html/index.html'
            EOF   
            
  #Etiquetas
  tags = {
    Name = "Mi servidor con terraform"
  }
 }
```

I don't know if i can pass 'user_data' commands after the instance is created and pass it a captured output value in order to update the resource.

Or i don't know if there are other method

Thank you and sorry for the english

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 8):

You can referece IP address of `Instance_1` in the `user_data` of `Instance_2`
if this is what you are after.

An example of that is below. Threat it more as a pseudo-code though, rather than a  working example.

```
resource "aws_instance" "Instance_1" {
  # create the first instance
}

resource "aws_instance" "Instance_2" {

  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              echo "${aws_instance.Instance_1.public_ip}" > /tmp/instance1_ip
            EOF 
}
```

In the above,`${aws_instance.Instance_1.public_ip}` will resolve to
the IP address of your `Instance_1`.

Answer (score 3):

Marcin's answer correctly answers the question, regarding putting the private IP in the user_data. However, I disagree with using this approach in the first place.

**Argumentation:**

- Whenever the IP of instance_1 changes, you will need to recreate instance_2 on a consecutive `terraform apply`, since this will alter the user data, and thus forces instance recreation. Even if it would not, changing the user data has no direct effect on the environment variables of instance_2, since user data only executes on instance creation, or on each instance boot, depending on how you configure it.
- Instance IP addresses change whenever you reboot or relaunch EC2 instances. This **will** happen at some point in the future, even outside of your control (e.g. AWS deprecating the instance from its services). The only way to prevent IP change is to assign a fixed, manually defined private IP to the instance, in which case you do not need to put it in the user_data dynamically to begin with, since you'd know the IP and it would never change, just like a URL endpoint.

**Suggestions:**

- [Use a private hosted zone, point an A record to instance_1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html), and pass the URL instead of the IP to e.g. the user_data of instance_2. This way, you can change the IP of instance_1, then change the endpoint of the record, and fix the situation without needing to change instance_2.
- Use an Elastic IP. This costs a small amount of money, but you will have a fixed public IP (which you can shield from the outside world by using security groups with your EC2 instances). Whenever the instance IP changes, its public IP will remain unchanged as long as you have the elastic IP attached.
- Use a fixed private IP address; see argumentation.

Comment: So the better option would be use an static or fixed IP or something? what do you mean by "fixed record to the DNS"?

Comment: @DiegoCamiloPeñaRamirez My answer was a bit vague on that point. I've updated the suggestion with a link to AWS' documentation, on how to use a private hosted zone to have a fixed internal URL for your instance. With 'fixed', I mean, the URL does not change if your instance IP ever changes. All you need to do is point the record (e.g. instance1.myinternalsite.com) to the new IP of instance1. You can achieve all of this in Terraform without having to relaunch instances to update user data.